# Netlogo, assigning variable to neighbors

Tags: netlogo, neighbours

I have a problem with my code, 
I am making a land use model where I want to give patches that have a surplus a new land use. To determine to what land-use the patch should change is based on the attractiveness of its neighbors.

Patches own = land-use willingtochange and attractiveness

What I want:
The patches that are willing to change, should change their land-use to the Land-use of the neighbor with the highest attractiveness (the closer to 0 the more attractive)

I tried to do this with the following statement:

```
to askforchange
  ask patches [
    if Willingstochange = true  [change]   ;; this ask the patches that are willing to change (have a surpuls) to go and change
  ]
end


to change
  ask neighbors with [Willingstochange = false ]  [         ;; this asks if the patch had neigbors with a shortage
  set Atractiveneighbor min-one-of patches [atractiveness]  ;; this asks to give the neigbor with the lowest patchcount/senario ratio
  ]


  ask patches with [Willingstochange = true]  [
    set Land-use ([Land-use] of Atractiveneighbor)   ;; this asks the patches to change their land-use to the land-use of neigbor with the lowest patchcount/senario ratio
  ]     

end
```

However Netlogo reports when running: "OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle or patch but got the number 0 instead."

Anyone suggestions how to code it way what it works?

My whole code:

```
extensions [gis]
globals
[
  land-use-map
   Senario1N               ;; the count of patches senario 1 describes
   Senario1L
   Senario1A
   Senario1B
   Senario1I
   Senario1R
   Senario1W
  %landusetypeN           ;; the amount patches
  %landusetypeL
  %landusetypeA
  %landusetypeB
  %landusetypeI
  Atractiveneighbor

]

patches-own
  [   Land-use                ;; Wat kind og landusetype a patch has
      Willingstochange        ;; If true a patch would like to change (if true the count of patches has a surplus comparing to the sneario, if false they have a shortage)
      atractiveness           ;; if a patch type is attractive to change in <1 = yess
    ]



to setup
  clear-all
  load-gis                       ;;load the maps
  setup-constants
  update-global-variables
  update-display
  reset-ticks
end



to load-gis  ;;load the maps
  set land-use-map gis:load-dataset "a_LANDUSE_cellsize5.asc"     ;;loads the land use map
  gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of land-use-map          ;;sets the envelope of the world to match that of the GIS dataset
  gis:apply-raster land-use-map Land-use                          ;;patches in the land-use-map have a specific land-use now

  ask patches [
    if Land-use = 1 [ set pcolor Green ] ; Green = Nature         ;; patches have a certain color now
    if Land-use = 2 [ set pcolor red ] ; Dark red = Leisure
    if Land-use = 3 [ set pcolor Yellow ] ; Yellow = Agriculture
    if Land-use = 4 [ set pcolor brown ] ; brouwn = Buildup
    if Land-use = 5 [ set pcolor grey ] ; grey = roads
    if Land-use = 6 [ set pcolor pink ] ; pink = industry
    if Land-use = 7 [ set pcolor blue ] ; Blue = water
  ]
    resize-world 0 1633 0 780
    set-patch-size 1
end

to setup-constants
  set Senario1N 49174        ;; the count of patches senario 1 describes
  set Senario1L 17871
  set Senario1A 569970
  set Senario1B 34202
  set Senario1I 5540
  set Senario1R 34968
  set Senario1W 65594

end


to go ;; this asks the model to caculate certain variables defined below
  askforchange
  caculateWILLingtochange
  caculateAtrac
  tick
end


to update-display
  ask patches
  [ if Land-use = 1 [ set pcolor Green ]   ;; Green = Nature           
    if Land-use = 2 [ set pcolor red ]     ;; Dark red = Leisure
    if Land-use = 3 [ set pcolor yellow ]  ;; Yellow = Agriculture
    if Land-use = 4 [ set pcolor brown ]   ;; brouwn = Buildup
    if Land-use = 5 [ set pcolor grey ]    ;; grey = roads
    if Land-use = 6 [ set pcolor pink ]    ;; pink = industry
    if Land-use = 7 [ set pcolor blue ]    ;; Blue = water
    ] ;; patches have a certain color now
end

to update-global-variables
  if count patches > 0
    [ set %landusetypeN (count patches with [ Land-use = 1 ] / count patches) * 100
      set %landusetypeL (count patches with [ Land-use = 2 ] / count patches) * 100
      set %landusetypeA (count patches with [ Land-use = 3 ] / count patches) * 100
      set %landusetypeB (count patches with [ Land-use = 4 ] / count patches) * 100
      set %landusetypeI (count patches with [ Land-use = 6 ] / count patches) * 100
    ]
end



to caculateWILLingtochange
  Ask  patches [
    if count patches with [Land-use = 1] > Senario1N [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 1 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ] ]

    if count patches with [Land-use = 2] > Senario1L [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 2 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ] ]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 3] > Senario1A [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 3 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ] ]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 4] > Senario1B [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 4 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ] ]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 5] > Senario1R [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 5 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ]]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 6] > Senario1I [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 6 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ]]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 7] > Senario1W [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 7 ][
           set  Willingstochange True
         ] ]  ]
end

to caculateAtrac
  Ask  patches [
    if count patches with [Land-use = 1] > Senario1N [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 1 ][
           set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 1]/ Senario1N )
         ] ]

    if count patches with [Land-use = 2] > Senario1L [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 2 ][
           set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 2]/ Senario1L )
         ] ]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 3] > Senario1A [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 3 ][
           set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 3]/ Senario1A )
         ] ]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 4] > Senario1B [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 4 ][
            set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 4]/ Senario1B )
         ] ]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 5] > Senario1R [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 5 ][
            set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 5]/ Senario1R )
         ]]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 6] > Senario1I [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 6 ][
             set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 6]/ Senario1I )
         ]]
    if count patches with [Land-use = 7] > Senario1W [ ask patches with [ Land-use = 7 ][
             set  atractiveness (count patches with [Land-use = 7]/ Senario1W )
         ] ]  ]
end


to askforchange
  ask patches [
    if Willingstochange = true  [change]   ;; this ask the patches that are willing to change (have a surpuls) to go and change
  ]
end


to change
  ask neighbors with [Willingstochange = false ]  [         ;; this asks if the patch had neigbors with a shortage
  set Atractiveneighbor min-one-of patches [atractiveness]  ;; this asks to give the neigbor with the lowest patchcount/senario ratio
  ]

  ask patches with [Willingstochange = true]  [
    set Land-use ([Land-use] of Atractiveneighbor)   ;; this asks the patches to change their land-use to the land-use of neigbor with the lowest patchcount/senario ratio
  ]     

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are asking the `neighbors with [Willingstochange = false ]` to `set` the global variable Attractiveneighbor. So, if there aren't any neighbours unwilling to change, then that variable is at its default value (which is 0) because nobody sets it. Also, you actually want the minimum of neighbours, but are asking over all patches.

This fixes your immediate problem (untested). Note that the procedure only gets run for `patches with [Willingstochange = true]` so you don't need to check that within the procedure.

```
to change
  set Atractiveneighbor min-one-of neighbors [atractiveness]
  set Land-use ([Land-use] of Atractiveneighbor)
end
```

However, I suspect this is the only place in your code where you using the global variable Atractiveneighbor, in which case there is no need to have such a variable at all. Delete it from the variables list and use `let` instead of `set`.

```
to change
  let Atractiveneighbor min-one-of neighbors [atractiveness]
  set Land-use ([Land-use] of Atractiveneighbor) 
end
```

Even cleaner (though perhaps harder to read for a new NetLogo coder), you can do this:

```
to change
  set Land-use [Land-use] of min-one-of neighbors [atractiveness]
end
```

Even better, why have the check in a separate procedure? You can delete the change procedure entirely and do:

```
to askforchange
  ask patches with [Willingstochange]
  [ set Land-use [Land-use] of min-one-of neighbors [atractiveness]
  ]
end
```

As well as combining the two procedures, this replaces `ask patches [ if Willingstochange = true] []` with `ask patches with [ Willingstochange = true] []` (using `with`) and also takes advantage of the simpler `true` and `false` coding where `true` is assumed (you can use `not Willingstochange` instead of `Willingstochange = false` too.

Comment: I am still having some troubles as the model does not want to assign a attractiveness  value to the patches... Any idea where that problem comes from?

Comment: I can see atractiveness in the `patches-own` variable list. Is it possible you have spelled it differently? I am guessing that English is not your first language and you have misspelled it in the list but possibly spelled it correctly when trying to use it - I tried to keep your spelling, but I may well have accidentally changed it as I automatically spelled correctly when typing.

Comment: "the model does not want" — is there an error message, unexpected behavior, or what?